# SQL Case Statement If Null select columns from Table X where Y=Z

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a custom report whereby the invoices will either have a PO number in the PO_Number Column or they wont.

If they don't have a PO number I'm looking to get data from 4 Columns (Segment1, Segment2, Segment3 and Segment4) where 2 ID numbers are the same. In the same statement in the event that there is a PO number I want to pull the same 4 columns but where 2 different ID numbers match.

The SQL I have so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
AID.INVOICE_ID,
AID.AMOUNT,
AID.PERIOD_NAME,
GCC.SEGMENT1 as Organisation,
GCC.SEGMENT2,
GCC.SEGMENT3,
GCC.SEGMENT4,
INV.INVOICE_NUM,
INV.CREATION_DATE,
PO.SEGMENT1 as PO_Number,
SUP.VENDOR_NAME,
AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,
LINES.LINE_NUMBER


FROM
AP_INVOICES_All INV 
INNER JOIN
  AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL LINES 
  ON INV.INVOICE_ID = LINES.INVOICE_ID 
INNER JOIN
  AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL AID 
  ON INV.INVOICE_ID = AID.INVOICE_ID 
INNER JOIN
  GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GCC 
  ON AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID 
INNER JOIN
  POZ_SUPPLIERS_V SUP 
  ON INV.VENDOR_ID = SUP.VENDOR_ID 
LEFT JOIN
  PO_HEADERS_ALL PO 
  ON LINES.PO_HEADER_ID = PO.PO_HEADER_ID

WHERE
AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN 
(
  'REC_TAX',
  'NONREC_TAX'
)
AND LINES.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN 
(
  'TAX'
)

ORDER BY
AID.INVOICE_ID,
LINES.LINE_NUMBER
```

If there is a PO I want the match to be done on:

```
PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
```

And if there isn't a PO:

```
AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID = GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID
```

(I know I need to reference the PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL table somewhere but not sure where)

Any help would be great as I'm pretty new to SQL and don't know how to express what I want to achieve in SQL code.

Let me know if I haven't been clear on any parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can left join `PO_DISTRIBUTION_ALL` and create conditional join on `GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
AID.INVOICE_ID,
AID.AMOUNT,
AID.PERIOD_NAME,
GCC.SEGMENT1 as Organisation,
GCC.SEGMENT2,
GCC.SEGMENT3,
GCC.SEGMENT4,
INV.INVOICE_NUM,
INV.CREATION_DATE,
PO.SEGMENT1 as PO_Number,
SUP.VENDOR_NAME,
AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE,
LINES.LINE_NUMBER
FROM AP_INVOICES_All INV 
INNER JOIN  AP_INVOICE_LINES_ALL LINES 
  ON INV.INVOICE_ID = LINES.INVOICE_ID 
INNER JOIN  AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL AID 
  ON INV.INVOICE_ID = AID.INVOICE_ID 
LEFT JOIN PO_HEADERS_ALL PO 
  ON LINES.PO_HEADER_ID = PO.PO_HEADER_ID
LEFT JOIN PO_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL PDA 
  ON PO.PO_HEADER_ID = PDA.PO_HEADER_ID
INNER JOIN  GL_CODE_COMBINATIONS GCC
  ON GCC.CODE_COMBINATION_ID = nvl(PDA.CODE_COMBINATION_ID, AID.DIST_CODE_COMBINATION_ID)
INNER JOIN
  POZ_SUPPLIERS_V SUP 
  ON INV.VENDOR_ID = SUP.VENDOR_ID 
WHERE AID.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN (  'REC_TAX',  'NONREC_TAX')
AND LINES.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE NOT IN ('TAX')
ORDER BY
AID.INVOICE_ID,
LINES.LINE_NUMBER
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. Greatly appreciated !